# Extra empty table rows in XSLT html conversion and few other problems

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have few questions conserning XSLT to html conversion.

For some reason my xsl documents makes extra rows between every for-each loop. What can be the problem? Problem can be seen in html outputs.

Here's my xslt file

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" media-type="text/html" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>KT-linjan moduulit</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>KT-linja info</h1>
        <table border="double">
          <caption>Moduulit taulukoituna</caption>
          <tr>
            <th>identifier</th>
            <th>nimi</th>
            <th>kuvaus</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="production_line/unit/*">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="@modID" />
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="name" />
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="description" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
        <p>
          <b>HUOM:</b>
        </p>
        <p>ID's of the modules are unique!</p>
        <p>References between modules are correct!</p>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and XML file:

```
<production_line>
  <unit>
    <lift_module modID="LM001">
      <name>Päätynostin PN1</name>
      <description lang="fi">Nostaa paletin alakuljettimelta ylös Starter-moduulille</description>
      <conveyor type="BELT" level="down" feed="in">
        <description lang="fi">Palettikuljetin (ala)</description>
        <stopper />
      </conveyor>
      <conveyor type="BELT" level="up" feed="out">
        <description lang="fi">Palettikuljetin (ylä)</description>
        <stopper />
      </conveyor>
      <lift_shelf>
        <conveyor feed="in_out" type="BAND">
          <description lang="fi">Palettikuljetin (hissitaso)</description>
          <stopper />
        </conveyor>
        <description lang="fi">Liikkuva hissitaso</description>
      </lift_shelf>
      <sensor type="INDUCTIVE">
        <amount>2</amount>
      </sensor>
      <chassis type="SAFETY" width="500" heigth="1200" length="700">
        <sensor type="OPTIC">
          <amount>1</amount>
        </sensor>
      </chassis>
    </lift_module>
    <connection fromIDREF="LM001" toIDREF="SM001" />
  </unit>
  <unit>
    <starter_module modID="SM001">
      <name>Starter-moduuli ST1</name>
      <description lang="fi">Jakaa paletit kolmelle kuljettimelle</description>
      <conveyor type="BELT">
        <description lang="fi">Palettikuljetin (keski)</description>
        <stopper />
      </conveyor>
      <conveyor type="BELT">
        <description lang="fi">Palettikuljetin (syöttö1)</description>
        <stopper />
      </conveyor>
      <conveyor type="BELT">
        <description lang="fi">Palettikuljetin (syöttö2)</description>
        <stopper />
      </conveyor>
      <crossing />
      <crossing />
      <crossing />
      <sensor type="INDUCTIVE">
        <amount>3</amount>
      </sensor>
      <sensor type="OPTIC">
        <amount>3</amount>
      </sensor>
    </starter_module>
    <connection fromIDREF="SM001" toIDREF="WM001" />
  </unit>
  <unit>
    <workstation modID="WM001">
      <name>Työasema TA1</name>
      <description lang="fi">Sisältää vasemman ja oikean työpisteen</description>
      <conveyor type="BELT">
        <description lang="fi">Palettikuljetin (keski)</description>
        <stopper />
      </conveyor>
      <conveyor type="BELT">
        <description lang="fi">Palettikuljetin (vasen)</description>
        <stopper>stoppari</stopper>
      </conveyor>
      <conveyor type="BELT">
        <description lang="fi">Palettikuljetin (oikea)</description>
        <stopper />
      </conveyor>
      <crossing />
      <crossing />
      <crossing />
      <sensor type="INDUCTIVE">
        <amount>6</amount>
      </sensor>
      <sensor type="OPTIC">
        <amount>6</amount>
      </sensor>
      <switch type="push_button" operate="manual">send-painike</switch>
      <switch type="switch" operate="manual">pause-kytkin</switch>
    </workstation>
    <connection fromIDREF="WM001" toIDREF="LM002" />
  </unit>
  <unit>
    <lift_module modID="LM002">
      <name>Päätynostin PN2</name>
      <description lang="fi">Laskee paletin ylhäältä alas paluukuljettimelle</description>
      <conveyor type="BELT" level="down" feed="out">
        <description lang="fi">Palettikuljetin (ala)</description>
        <stopper />
      </conveyor>
      <conveyor type="BELT" level="up" feed="in">
        <description lang="fi">Palettikuljetin (ylä)</description>
        <stopper />
      </conveyor>
      <lift_shelf>
        <description lang="fi">Liikkuva hissitaso</description>
        <conveyor type="BELT" feed="in_out">
          <description lang="fi">Palettikuljetin (hissitaso)</description>
          <stopper />
        </conveyor>
      </lift_shelf>
      <sensor type="INDUCTIVE">
        <amount>2</amount>
      </sensor>
      <chassis type="SAFETY" width="500" heigth="1200" length="700">
        <sensor type="OPTIC">
          <amount>2</amount>
        </sensor>
      </chassis>
    </lift_module>
  </unit>
</production_line>
```

On left is my table and on the right table in correct format.

[image: Screenshot]

I need to check if every identifier has unique attribute name (modID, for example LM001) and post if its unique or not. How should this check be performed?

I also need to check if iDREF atributes in XML file are properly linked. For example in the end of first  node there is  and check that it is correctly linked to the next modID. Any idea about this one?

It also seems to add unnecessary row between "ID's of the modules are unique!" and "References between modules are correct!" lines (where should be posted the answers of the checks).

Answer (score 0):

Don't do `<xsl:for-each select="production_line/unit/*">`. That is too unspecific, it also matches the `<connection>` elements (which generate the empty rows).

Do this instead: `<xsl:for-each select="production_line/unit/lift_module">`.

---

To check whether all `modID` values are uniqe, try to select a duplicate:

```
<xsl:variable name="duplicateModIds" select="
  //*/@modID[
    . = preceding::*/@modID
    or
    . = following::*/@modID
  ]
" />

<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="$duplicateModIds">
    <p>IDs of the modules are NOT unique!</p>
    <!-- probably output $duplicateModIds, too -->
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <p>IDs of the modules are unique.</p>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Note that this can also be solved more elegantly through an XSL key, but for now the "duct tape" solution should be fine. Think about using keys when the performance of your transformation starts to drop or your requirements become more complex.

---

To check whether all connections are correct, simply try to select an incorrect one:

```
<xsl:variable name="incorrectRefs" select="
  //connection[
    @fromIDREF != ../*/@modID
    or (
      ../following-sibling::unit[1]
      and @toIDREF != ../following-sibling::unit[1]/*/@modID
    )
  ]
" />

<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="$incorrectRefs">
    <p>References between modules are NOT correct!</p>
    <!-- probably output $incorrectRefs, too -->
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <p>References between modules are correct.</p>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

also need to check if iDREF atributes in XM

Comment: Thank you for your help. I need to follow your help for questions 2 and 3 later today. 

I don't think that solution 1 works because all modules are with different names (lift module, starter module etc.)? All of them have modID though. So is there a way to exclude <connection> from there to prevent spaces for happening?

Comment: Solution for the first problem was xsl:for-each select="production_line/unit/*[@modID]. This way it excludes connections.

Comment: Same for the other checks.